# Point [ui-router otherwise] to static page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have `login.html` with different layout than other sites so I've put it in my **app** directory and I do not have state for it.
However I'd like to redirect to `www.example/login.html` if user get 404.

I tried to get it by configuring ui-router inside of one module:

```
function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider, $windowProvider) {
    var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $window){
        $window.location.href = '/login.html';
    });
}
```

But unfortunatelly I got

> Error: $window.location is undefined

How can I redirect to this 'static page'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `otherwise` is a callback function of which, is a closure itself so your `var $window = $windowProvider.$get()` is **NOT** the same as the argument `$window` in your callback function, and hence the undefined.

The correct code should be:

```
function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider, $windowProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector){
        var $window = $windowProvider.$get(); // put this line of code inside
        $window.location.href = '/login.html';
    });
}
```